# Draw video on canvas ios can't autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, ios, canvas

This code works fine on mac
Add onload:main() to the body tag
Can run automatically after startup
In the ios browser can not run automatically, after setting a button, click to point to main(). Click to play normally
under ios
onload cannot be executed

Both mac and ios use safari browser. How to make ios autoplay normal

```
function main() { 


const video1= initializeVideo("mv/m4.mp4"); 
VIDEO_CANVAS = document.getElementById('video');

video1.addEventListener('loadeddata', (event) => { 

const context = VIDEO_CANVAS.getContext("2d");


context.canvas.width =  video1.videoWidth * (740 / video1.videoHeight);
context.canvas.height = 740; 



processVideos(video1,0);
}); 
} 


function processVideos(video1,frame1){

if(frame1 <=200 ) 

{  showVideoFrame(video1,frame1);  frame1++;  }
if(frame1>=200) {
     location.reload();
        }
        

    setTimeout(function(){

        processVideos(video1,frame1);
    },30);
}
function showVideoFrame(video,frame){
    var time = frame /  30 ;
    video.currentTime=time;
    const context=VIDEO_CANVAS.getContext("2d");
    
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, VIDEO_CANVAS.width,VIDEO_CANVAS.height);
    }
function initializeVideo(filename) {
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src=filename; 
video.load(); 
return video; 
}
```

body content

```
<body onload="main()">
 <center> 
 <canvas id="video"></canvas>
 </center>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the idea to slow motion the video? It is not easy to jump from frame to frame, because you don't know how much of the video has been loaded. In this example I use the property `defaultPlaybackRate` on the video to control the speed. And then simply play the video and draw the current frame to the canvas every 30 ms. The interval is cleared when the video has ended.

#### Update

If this is going to autoplay you can try to mute the video before playing it. An alternative could be to let the user interact with the page first, either clicking something (click event) or scrolling (scroll event) a bit. You can read more about it here: [Autoplay guide for media and Web Audio APIs - Web media technologies | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)

```js
var VIDEO_CANVAS, interval;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  VIDEO_CANVAS = document.getElementById('video');
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  video.defaultPlaybackRate = .4;
  video.muted = true; // important for autoplay
  
  video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', e => {
    VIDEO_CANVAS.width = e.target.videoWidth * (200 / e.target.videoHeight);
    VIDEO_CANVAS.height = 200;
    
    e.target.play();
    interval = setInterval(function() {showVideoFrame(video);}, 30);
  });
  video.addEventListener('ended', e => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
  
  video.src = "https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/rabbit320.mp4";
});

function showVideoFrame(video) {
  const context = VIDEO_CANVAS.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, VIDEO_CANVAS.width, VIDEO_CANVAS.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="video"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

The code I posted works fine, but only in the macbook. The frame range in which the video can be autoplayed after running.
 
But not in ios

I tried adding a button to run main(). Can be played on ios, but can't open direct autoplay

Comment: @moze2022 OK, I missed that part of your question. As I understand this is a general issue (autoplaying). Try to mute the video before playing it. I updated my answer.